# Gimp - White / Gray Line from Transforming and Copying

Tags: gimp

When ever I stretch a portion of the image via Transform, a faint line will be produced from the point of the stretch/transform.

Likewise when I copy and paste a portion of the image into a layer, that new layer will be surrounded by a faint line.

The biggest problem is that when I export this out to jpeg, it is more visible.

Does any one know how I can get rid of this faint line?

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqwWR.jpg

I tried different version of GIMP, 2.8.20, 2.8.22 and 2.10.8, all result in the same issue.

Cheers

Comment: Do you have a "Feather edges" set in the rectangle selection option?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Just checked. Feather Edge is turned off :(

Comment: No idea then. Ca you post some small sample before and after XCF's somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this problems, and after trying some different options, I found that unselecting the option "Antialiasing" in the selection tool fixed the problem for me.

See image:

[image: Screenshot]